# Finding whether or not group of cells has repeated values

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with a list of items by group. I need to find if there is any repeated values in each of these groups. These "repeated" values are not exact. The values are to be considered repeated if one group contains both item "123" and item "123i". Any numeric differences are fine, I am simply looking for the items within each group that may have the same numeric key, regardless of the fact that one may have an i and one may not.

In summary, how do I find repeated values within a specific group for only the first three characters of each cell? I have tried using variations of COUNTIF, and ISNUMBER(SEARCH, yet have not had any success yet.

Thanks.

```
B109
B109i
B111
B111i
B154
B156
B330
B350

B109i
B111i
B130i
B140i
B154i
B156i
B330
B350
```

Above is an example of two groups. In the first group, B109 and B109i are repeated as well as B111 and B111i are repeated. The second group contains no repeats. Ideally the output would list the values (B109^B109i) in a cell next to the group that are repeated. The next best output would simply to list "yes" or "no" at the bottom of each group if there are repeated values.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could share a sample of a "Specific Group" and what you expect the output to be of the duplicates in this group. I get, overall, what you are asking, but I don't understand, specifically, what are you trying to get here. Do you want a formula that looks at a range and spits out "Duplicates", "Not Duplicates" (for instance).

Comment: If you're using VBA, you'll want to utilize `InStr`

Comment: Would you mind having a helper column? Are all your values in format: letter,3 numbers, [letter]?

Comment: @NiteshHalai Yes, sorry for late response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub TestInStr()
Dim i As Long

'From row 1 to 10
For i = 1 To 10
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
        'Referencing column A
        If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 1), ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)) Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i + 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) & "^" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 1)
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]